# Can Android speak to a PC not running Java?

Tags: android, tcp

Basic question before I get too far into coding.  I was told once that in order for the Android Phone to contact a PC server, that server must be written in Java.  I find this a little convoluted, but is this the case?  Or by using the TCP/IP classes (Socket), can I just read and write binary data over the pipe regardless of who or how the server was written?

Comment: Android phones talk to Apache and IIS (webservers) all the time, and they aren't written in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TCP/IP is language agnostic, you can create a client/server implementation in any language or platform that supports TCP/IP and communicate with any other TCP/IP connection.

The communication over the protocol is dependent on implementation though so you need to make sure that both client and server implementations understand the communication going over the sockets.

Answer (score 1):

You can write data regardless of what kind of server it is. Whether it's written in Java, PHP, C++, or whatever does not matter. As long as the server knows how to read and write to/from sockets. I've had my Android phone connect to a PHP server today, so either my phone is disobeying the laws of the universe, or...

Also, the same applies for the other way around, it is possible to make clients for other platforms than Android to connect to a server.

Comment: Outstanding, thanks Simon.  I figured that was the case, but wanted to make sure before I went in guns blazing as it were.

Answer (score 1):

> I was told once that in order for the Android Phone to contact a PC
>   server, that server must be written in Java.

That is incorrect. The **whole point of** TCP/IP was to create a set of rules, a protocol to allow communication across different devices, architectures, operating systems etc.

**Any [TCP/IP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_protocol_suite)** client can communicate with any TCP/IP server period. No exceptions. (provided they implement a common version of the protocol that is)

Comment: I was a little bit scared at first when you started with `That is incorrect`, but then I continued reading to understand what you meant by `That`.